# Armazenando unidade de medida em tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Em um dos meus formulários será necessário coletar a altura do usuário em metros. Porém, esse formulário pode estar em inglês ou em português. Caso esteja em inglês esta altura será em pés (feet). Caso esteja em português a altura será em metros.

A melhor pratica seria ter uma coluna para pés e outra para metros em minha tabela? Ou somente em metros? Qual seria o melhor *data type* para minha coluna armazenar esse dado?

Comment: Eu diria que depende da sua regra de negócio, mas você pode colocar em metros e quando a unidade vier em pés, apenas converta usando trigger ou antes mesmo de chamar o banco.

Comment: E qual seria o melhor tipo de dado para armazenar metros?

Comment: Se não for fazer contas com ele, char, se for, float ou decimal, se necessitar de um número preciso.

Comment: No caso de eu querer que seja possível valor em metros do tipo : 1,5 metros, 10,4 metros, 3 metros. Decimal (10,1) seria a melhor escolha para armazenar?

Comment: `Decimal(10,1)` é o mesmo que `9999999999,9`. Poderia colocar `Decimal(2,2)`.

Comment: Blz brother. problema resolvido =)

Comment: Observção  Altura nos EUA é em geral informada em pés e polegadas tipo 6'6''  ,  5-10 etc a média teria de ser calcula transformando tudo em polegadas (1 pé = 12 plogadas) e revertendo depois para ft/in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sempre digo que informações que são apenas descritivas devem ser do tipo caractere (`VARCHAR`, por exemplo). Somente informações que envolvem contas devem usar tipos numéricos (`DECIMAL`, `FLOAT`, por exemplo).

Este é um caso curioso. Se você usar uma *string* (`VARCHAR`), o ideal é que tenha duas colunas, uma para cada unidade, afinal você tem duas descrições.

Não vai na onda de que o banco de dados não deve ter duas colunas com o mesmo dado porque neste caso o dado é diferente.

Claro que o ideal aí também seria que a entrada dos dois dados sejam independentes. Se você for calcular um deles, aí a coisa muda um pouco.

Nada impede de fazer desta forma mesmo que uma das medidas seja calculada. Mas se é calculada, já começa ser melhor usar um tipo numérico, certo?

Nem tanto, aí vai depender do contexto específico. Eventualmente um cálculo básico só para inserir o dado pode não ser considerado um cálculo. Em geral eu consideraria na maioria das situações, mas não sei a sua.

Se você preferir ter apenas uma coluna, ok, mas aí terá que calcular a outra medida todas as vezes e o tipo caractere não é ideal. Tem que pensar bem o que é melhor para seu caso. Se tiver duas colunas e só vai exibir, aí não terá este cálculo.

O tipo caractere é útil para apresentar a informação em formato "mais humano" como demonstra o comentário do Motta acima.

Se adotar o campo numérico, então precisa decidir o quanto necessita de precisão e exatidão. Os tipos `FLOAT` ou `DOUBLE` tem [problemas de arredondamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101). E se você não pode ter este tipo de problema, sugiro fortemente não só usar o tipo `DECIMAL` ou `INTEGER`, mas também ter duas colunas e armazenar as duas medidas independentemente. Assim você tem controle sobre como fazer o arredondamento.

Se não fizer desta forma, se precisar somar as medidas, por exemplo, terá resultados diferentes dependendo da unidade usada. Não tem outra forma de resolver isto.

Se a exatidão não é importante, se a informação não precisará ser confrontada ou manipulada em conjunto posteriormente, os tipos inexatos podem ser usados. Mas sinceramente eu os evitaria mesmo assim.

Nestes casos eu prefiro não ter casas decimais, prefiro usar a medida básica que evite isto. Se é altura, grave o número de centímetros ou até mesmo de milímetros, se isto for necessário, não use metros. E use um tipo que só trabalha com inteiros. O mesmo vale para polegadas, não use pés. O que fica até difícil calcular.

**Importante**: Mesmo usando parte inteira, a conversão pode causar inexatidões, portanto se não pode conviver com isto, adote uma estratégia de arredondamento e guarde os dois dados.

Se guardar apenas um dado, você pode se perguntar qual deve ser guardado. Eu iria no mais exato, ou seja, nos centímetros. Não é "tanto faz".

Mas lembre-se que não há problema em manter duas colunas se elas forem úteis. Cuidado com as tais das boas práticas, as pessoas as usam cegamente. E muitas vezes as pessoas só sabem delas pela metade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vou seguir seus conselhos. Vlw

Answer (score 0):

> A melhor pratica seria ter uma coluna para pés e outra para metros em
>   minha tabela?

Não, lembre-se que em um banco de dados você não deve ter colunas diferentes com o mesmo dado, pois gera alguns problemas, por exemplo quando precisar atualizar vai ter que atualizar duas colunas diferentes. Se precisar desse valor como chave estrangeira qual coluna iria usar?

> Ou somente em metros? Qual seria o melhor data Type para minha coluna
>   armazenar esse dado?

Eu escolheria uma unidade padrão, metros ou pés tanto faz, e criaria uma única coluna no banco para registrar esse valor. Para valores precisos o ideal é usar decimal e especificar o numero de casas decimais, e não float pois dependendo da conta o resultado pode variar. Usar string faz com que consultas envolvendo contas fiquem mais lentas.

Para resolver o problema de como o dado será posteriormente lido do banco, você tem varias formas de implementar a solução.

Pode criar uma stored procedure que tenha como um dos parâmetros a unidade que deseja o valor da altura e converter diretamente usando sql.

Pode criar uma camada de serviço intermediaria que tenha uma função com a mesma funcionalidade descrita acima.

Ou ainda, converter o valor diretamente na interface cliente dependendo de qual unidade de medida é selecionada.

Mais importante que como registrar o dado é saber como ele será utilizado para poder escolher a melhor forma de persistência e leitura do mesmo.